# Evaluate a number in a vector with positive integers, negative integers, NA and blank

Tags: r

say I have a vector with pos and neg integers and also NA and blank values.  I want to run a loop that evaluates each vector element and return what type of integer it is.  Here is an example

```
x <- c(-1, 1, NA, "")

for (i in 1:length(x)) {

  if (x[i] <= 0) {

    print("non-positive number")

  } else if (x[i] > 0) {

    print("positive")

  } else {

    print("not a number")

  }

}
```

the above code works fine for integers but when encounters NA and blanks it does not print "not a number"

I could modify my conditional but why the last else condition does not work.

any thoughts?

Comment: A vector cannot contain more than one class. In your `x`, all elements will be converted to characters. Your question makes sense if `x` is a `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if an element is `NA` first:

```r
x <- c(-1, 1, NA, "", "abc", NULL, 1000.2, "1000.2")

for (i in x) {
  i_numeric <- tryCatch(as.numeric(i), warning = function(w) {})
  if (is.null(i_numeric) || is.na(i_numeric)) {
    print("not a number")
  } else if (i <= 0) {
    print("non-positive number")
  } else if (i > 0) {
    print("positive")
  } else {
    print("not a number")
  }
}
```

Note that:

a. You don't need to loop through the `length` of `x`.

b. @Darren Tsai's comment is correct, your `x` values are characters however in R:

```
"1" > 0
```

```
TRUE
```

But you should be aware of that. I've edited my answer to include also weird values such as non-empty strings and `NULL`s.

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, you can't really input a `NULL` element in the vector `x`, it will not be iterated over. You can if `x` was a list though.

Comment: If there exist any characters except for `""` in `x`, the comparison to zero will get some trouble. Although I think it's not the OP's case, you can try to put `"abc"` in `x` and run your method, a weird output will occur.

Comment: Giora, THANKS!!!!   I ran your code and noticed that it print statements is triggered 7 times but your x vector has 8 elements.  The code did not print anything for NULL value.  any thoughts?

Comment: @seakyourpeak That's so cool, if you print `x` you'll get `[1] "-1"     "1"      NA       ""       "abc"    "1000.2" "1000.2"`, because `NULL` can't be a part of a vector, so we can't iterate over it. It can be part of a list, though, which would make more sense in this case in general.

Comment: BTW @seakyourpeak if you're satisfied with the answer you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above your `x` is a character. You can verify that using `str(x)`. You might as well do a character comparison as follows:

```
x <- c(-1, 1, -10, 12, 1001, NA, "", "xyz")

# A helper function to check if x contains a alphabets
is.letter <- function(x) grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", x)

for(i in seq_along(x)){
  if(!nzchar(x[i])){
    print("not a number")
  } else if(is.na(x[i])){
    print("not a number")
  } else if(is.letter(x[i])){
    print("not a number")
  } else if(x[i] > "0") {

    print("positive")

  } else {
    print("non-positive number")
  }

}
#Output 
# [1] "non-positive number"
# [1] "positive"
# [1] "non-positive number"
# [1] "positive"
# [1] "positive"
# [1] "not a number"
# [1] "not a number"
# [1] "not a number"
```